# Error when creating a table in a Microsoft Word document from pure Javascript

Tags: javascript

What I need to do is create a simple table in a MS Word document from js and have it downloaded upon clicking a button. Luckily, I found some code that takes care of creating the document but I get this
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` in the console pointing to this line: `import * as fs from "fs";` as well as this one `import { BorderStyle, Document, Packer, Paragraph, Table, TableCell, TableRow } from "../build";`.

As a reference, here's the code I have:

```
import * as fs from "fs";
import { BorderStyle, Document, Packer, Paragraph, Table, TableCell, TableRow } from "../build";

function generate() {
    const doc = new docx.Document();
    //creating the table
    const table = new table({
        rows:[
           new TableRow({
               children: [
                   new TableCell({
                       children: [new Paragraph("Name")],
                   }),
                   new TableCell({
                       children: ["Date"],
                   }),
               ],
           }),
            
        ],
    });
    
    //section for title
    doc.addSection({
        properties: {},
        children: [
            new docx.Paragraph({
                children: [
                    new docx.TextRun("List"),
                ],
            }),
        ],
    });
    //section for table
    doc.addSection({
        children: [table],
    });
    docx.Packer.toBlob(doc).then(blob => {
        console.log(blob);
        saveAs(blob, "MyForm.docx");
        console.log("Document created successfully");
    });
}
```

I feel like I'm missing something completely obvious like not having something pre-downloaded or what not. All I have is my HTML and js file, nothing else. Either way, this is all fairly new to me.

Also as a side note: `npm install --save docx`. Tried googling and looking here at past posts but got confused. What does this npm do and is it relevant to my code?

Answer (score 0):

That is TypeScript code designed to be compiled to JavaScript and run through Node.js.

Web browsers do not provide the APIs needed to run it.

The [module itself](https://github.com/dolanmiu/docx) does claim to run in Node.js **and** browsers, but you can't just copy/paste a Node.js example and run it in a browser.

> What does this npm

NPM is a package manager for Node.js

Comment: Oh I see. How come the first link's code (https://jsfiddle.net/dolanmiu/kqxrj35u/1/) worked then? Is it because it's simple text being written to the MS Doc rather than tables?

Comment: @r_l  — I'm not going to do a full analysis, but the first obvious thing that stops this working outside of Node.js is the import of the `fs` module which only works in Node.js